How do I move a point in a specific direction in 3D Space?
I know how to move a point in a direction in 2D space it's like this:
pointX += sin(angle) * movementSpeed;
pointY += cos(angle) * movementSpeed;

How do I do the same in 3D space assuming the angle variable is replaced with pitch, yaw, and roll variables and the addition of a pointZ variable?

Sounds like you want to know how to convert from spherical coordinates to Cartesian. That's the 3D analogue of the 2D polar-to-Cartesian code you've shown. We have existing Q&A you can consult if the Wiki article doesn't cover what you need.

Possible duplicate: How do I translate a spherical coordinate to a Cartesian one?
